# invalid hexadecimal data: odd number of digits [PostgreSQL]

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9

When trying to insert data, i got something wrong.

This is working

```
INSERT INTO unicode_blocks_bytea(
        a, z, block_name)
VALUES 
(decode('FE50','hex'), decode('FE6F','hex'), 'Small Form Variants')
```

but this is not, i got error :

```
INSERT INTO unicode_blocks_bytea(
        a, z, block_name)
VALUES 
(decode('10000','hex'), decode('1007F','hex'), 'Linear B Syllabary')
```

the error is :

```
ERROR:  invalid hexadecimal data: odd number of digits
********** Error **********
ERROR: invalid hexadecimal data: odd number of digits
SQL state: 22023
```

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you are trying to convert from hex to decimal.  In this case, try this:

```
select x'10000'::integer
```

Result is

```
65536
```

Also

```
select x'1007f'::integer
```

Result is

```
65663
```

`encode` and `decode` are slightly different.  For example:

```
select decode('FE50','hex')
```

produces

```
\376P
```

Is this what you want?  I think you should say

```
select x'FE50'::integer
```

which gives you

```
65104
```

This is probably what you want because you seem to be recording the starting and ending codepoints of Unicode blocks.  I susepect the idea is you are trying to find the block for a given codepoint and for this you will want the integer values.

It is true that `encode`/`decode` don't like strings with an odd number of characters, but I don't think that is what you want.

Comment: is decode('010000','hex') will give the same result with decode('10000','hex') ?

Comment: Your intent is to produce 65536 decimal, I would suspect.  So yes.  It is somewhat surprising that PostgresQL is weird about 10000.

Comment: is this bugs ?. i'm confused.

Comment: i have large data, and must be inserted. what's the solutions

Comment: select decode('010000','hex') will give result \001\000\000;
select encode('\001\000\000','hex') will give result 010000;

but not 10000. It's different

Comment: @Thessa I edited the answer to use the correct way to convert hex to decimal.

Comment: exactly right, you understand what i want :) 
i want insert it to bytea data type. but i'm confused for the performance, which is better store in bytea and the match the string in hex format. or store the integer value and easy to match the string

Thanks so much Ray.

Comment: i mean better store an integer start and end codepoint or let it be hex value ?